# iPad App rejected. Now where should I publish it?

Tags: ipad, appstore-approval, kindle

I developed an iPad book-app, made of several slides, but unfortunately Apple rejected it because it shows screenshots of their trademarks.

Now, what should I do? I don't think I'll find a good solution in the Resolution Center.

Which are in your opinion the markets where I can publish these slides? [Lulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lulu.com)? [Kindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle) (but they are with colors)? A [PayPal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PayPal) button and a website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a dispute with Apple, not programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question for Apple App Store developer support, not a question about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 3):

You could **really** easily edit out the trademarks in the photos and resubmit.

Comment: No, to change Apple Logo or Apple-owned graphic symbol is to say to make my app empty :( This was their statement...

You may not use the Apple Logo or any other Apple-owned graphic symbol, logo, or icon on or in connection with web sites, products, packaging, manuals, promotional/advertising materials, or for any other purpose except pursuant to an express written trademark license from Apple, such as a reseller agreement. p.s. I tried with other guides, which they accepted, Aptana and Gimp...

Answer (score 0):

You can start by putting it on the Cydia store. It's not great, but your app is ready anyway.

Comment: Can you add a reference to Cydia? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)